# Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, netbeans, jdbc

I'm using latest version of MySQL ==> mysql-5.6.10-winx64.zip

Created the database and every thing is ok 'I think'
when I try to execute this simple command;

```
"select * from family"
```

I got this error :

> Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT' at
>   line 1

I've spent much time searching for a solution but no solution was found :(

Comment: show all the query you have executed, I can't see `OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT` on your select query.

Comment: what are you using to query the database? - Sounds like a GUI / tool might be adding extra stuff to your query before executing it

Comment: run `show variables where variable_name = 'sql_select_limit';` check if it's numeric?

Comment: try setting it to UINT32_MAX max value `4294967295`. `set sql_select_limit = 4294967295;` Default is supposed to be UINT64_MAX(18446744073709551615).

Comment: @Steve I wrote the query in netbeans in the

Comment: @Steve I wrote the query in netbeans in the "execute command" window

Comment: @DoSparKot Yes it's numeric and equal to 18446744073709551615

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That looks like an error coming from a JDBC driver. When the JDBC driver initializes the connection, it sends several commands to the MySQL server, one of which is:

```
SET OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT
```

The problem is that the `SET OPTION` syntax has been deprecated for some time and is now no longer valid in MySQL 5.6. Here's a relevant bug conversation from MySQL's bug database:

[Bug #66659: mysql 5.6.6m9 fails on OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66659)

Try upgrading your JDBC MySQL driver. The bug conversation lists some other options in case upgrading the driver is not an option.

Answer (score 11):

I followed the instructions above and this worked for me!

1. Download latest jar file from here:
   http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=412737
   Unzip it
   Copy jar file "mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar" 
   to this folder: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3\ide\modules\ext
2. In Netbeans IDE: Disconnect from database. 
   Click Services. Expand Drivers. Right-click on MySQL and press Customize.
   Add latest driver
   Remove previous driver.
3. Re-connect to dabatase within IDE.

Comment: I was modifying a Tomcat server: Tomcat/lib/ext/mysql.jar , but besides that the replacement made it work!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem few weeks back. Followed the following steps and it very much resolved the issue.

1. Copied the latest version (mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin) of the jar file to ..\NetBeans 7.3\ide\modules\ext. My earlier version of the driver was mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.
2. Change the driver version within NetBeans IDE. In the IDE's Services window, expand Drivers -> right-click on MySQL (Connector/J driver) and select Customize. Remove the earlier driver and point it to the latest one (C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.3\ide\modules\ext\mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar). Click ok and restart IDE.

This should resolve the problem.

Comment: I came across similar working on a play project, "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.26", did the trick

Answer (score 1):

If the driver suggestion does not work, check your sql for unprintable characters. I just spent an hour troubleshooting this issue only to discover a hidden u+200b character at the end of my sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same Error when i was dumping mysql table structure file in to DB. Mistake was putting the Syntax for dropping all table before but not checking their existence in the Database.
Issue was at " **DROP TABLE usermgmt**".
I removed that code of lines of dropping tables and it proceeded with out any error this time.

Comment: Did you have a statement ending in ';' in drop command when running all commands at once?

Answer (score 0):

I prefixed the name of the table with the database name such as

```
select * from database_name.table_name;
```

and it worked perfectly, so most likely there's a name conflict.