# NetBeans can SELECT all columns except Primary Key field

Tags: mysql, sql, netbeans

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113707/error-code-1064-sql-state-42000-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax), the solution for which did not work for me.

I'm using NetBeans to connect to a MySQL database (all running locally, all latest versions, latest JDBC driver).  I have created a simple table and populated it with a few rows of data:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENTS(
    STUDENTID INTEGER not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(30),
    LASTNAME VARCHAR(30),
    EMAIL VARCHAR(60)
);

INSERT INTO STUDENTS values ( null, 'Joe', 'Shmoe', 'joeshmoe@email.com' );
```

Using the MySQL command line, I can verify that the data made it into the database (SELECT *).  However, when I issue that same SELECT command in NetBeans, I get this weird error:

```
In NetBeans

    SELECT * FROM Students;

    Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
    check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
    syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT' at line 1
    Line 12, column 1
```

I also tried issuing the statement long form, which throws the error.  However, when I omit the primary key field from the long form statement, it returns data:

```
In NetBeans

SELECT STUDENTID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL FROM STUDENTS; <-- THROWS 1064 ERROR
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL FROM STUDENTS;            <-- WORKS???
```

I don't have any idea what this error means.  Forum posts on the internet point to an old bug that has since been fixed, so I don't believe it has anything to do with NetBeans (maybe I'm wrong?).  Can anybody offer any insight into what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.  It turns out that this bug has been corrected in the latest mysql jdbc driver.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/